# AJAX Post Custom Plugin WordPress slows down all of the web site

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, performance

I am writ plugin for WordPress. It sends a link to the images on the PHP file (Ajax).
The array consists of 10 photos.

```
obj.photos.push({ img_url: img_url, source: source, photo_text: photo_text, tag: tag });

    var data_insert = {
        action: 'instapin_insert',
        data: obj

    };

    $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/wp-content/plugins/instapin/ajax.php',
              data: data_insert,
        });
```

Next, the file takes a picture and the script loads to the cloud with Google (Google Drive).

```
<?php 

session_start();
session_write_close();


require_once('../../../wp-config.php'); 

global $service;


if(class_exists('INSTAPIN'))
{       
    $instapin = new INSTAPIN();

}

$google_drive = get_option('instapin_drive');

$photos_array = $_POST['data']['photos'];

    // Создаём объект записи
      $instapin_post = array(
         'post_title' => 'Название записи',
         'post_content' => '',
         'post_status' => 'draft',
         'post_author' => 1,
         'post_category' => array(0)
      );

    // Вставляем запись в базу данных
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $instapin_post );


    if($google_drive == 'on'){


        $folder = get_option('google_upload_folder');       
        $found = false;         

        $files = $service->files->listFiles();
        foreach ($files['items'] as $item) {
            if ($item['title'] == $post_id) {
                $folder_insert_photo = $item['id'];
                $found = true;
            break;
            }
        }

        if($found == false){
            $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
            //Setup the Folder to Create
            $file->setTitle($post_id);
            $file->setDescription('Photo folder: post_id - ' . $post_id);
            $file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');

            //Set the ProjectsFolder Parent
            $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
            $parent->setId( $folder );
            $file->setParents(array($parent));

            //create the ProjectFolder in the Parent
            $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
                'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
            ));

            $folder_insert_photo = $createdFile->id;

            $instapin->insertPermission($service, $folder_insert_photo, 'id', 'anyone', 'reader');

        }


        $count = 1;

        $photo = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $parent_folder = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();

        foreach($photos_array as $item){

            if($count == 40){
                break;
            }

            $img_url = strtok($item['img_url'], '?');
            $image_url = str_replace("s150x150/", "", $img_url);

            $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data
            $filename = basename($image_url); // Create image file name
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );
            $MimeType = $wp_filetype['type'];

            $seo_name = $item['tag'] . '_' . $count . '.jpg';

            //Setup the Folder to Create
            $photo->setTitle($seo_name);
            $photo->setDescription('Photo: ' .  $image_url);
            $photo->setMimeType($MimeType);


            $parent_folder->setId( $folder_insert_photo );
            $photo->setParents(array($parent_folder));

            // Try to upload the file, you can add the parameters e.g. if you want to convert a .doc to editable google format, add 'convert' = 'true'
            $createdPhoto = $service->files->insert($photo, array(
                'data' => $image_data,
                'mimeType' => $MimeType,
                'uploadType'=> 'multipart'
            ));

            $instapin->insertPermission($service, $createdPhoto->id, 'id', 'anyone', 'reader');

            $filePath = "GoogleDrive/{$folder_insert_photo}/{$seo_name}";
            $fullFile = "https://googledrive.com/host/{$folder_insert_photo}/{$seo_name}";

            print_r($fullFile);

            $count++;
        }


    }



?>
```

But when I send an AJAX post to upload 10 photos, all admin panel and front. Nothing can be done and go until the download is complete (the script works).
But when I post to download 10 photos, all admin panel and front crashes (hangs). Nothing can be done and go until the upload is finished (the script works).
How to make this multi-tasking? So the admin panel and front continue to work, and the script is working in the background.